Как позволить активировать функцию только после нажатия кнопки
Мне нужно, что бы активация Button2 позволялась только при условии, что перед этим была нажата Button1, так же, после нажатия кнопки Button2 все возвращалось к исходному положению(Условию нажатия Button1)
<button id="Button1" onclick="Button1()">B1</button>
<button id="Button2" onclick="Button2()">B2</button>

function Button1() {
   //Код кнопки
}
function Button2() {
   alert("Кнопка нажата")
   //Код возврата к исходному положению
}



нужно, что бы активация Button2 позволялась только при условии, что перед этим была нажата Button1


Делаете изначально свойство disabled у Button2 на true, а у Button1 - на false  (.disabled = false или .disabled = true)
При клике на Button1 - меняете эти свойства у кнопкок на противоположные


после нажатия кнопки Button2 все возвращалось к исходному положению(Условию нажатия Button1)


При клике на Button2 - меняете свойство disabled на true, а у Button1 - на false


Спасибо большое
